# Flood filling in order to get availabe cells

Tags: python-2.7, flood-fill

I'm trying to implement the flood fill algorithm in order to find all available cells for my robot in a grid. (0 means available, 1 means occupied).
My input is a grid (matrix) that does not have to be squared, and x and y coordinates from which I start the flood fill algorithm.
My question is:
I'm trying to initialize a set in which I only collect reachable cells,
but for some reason I get this error:
I only get the (0,0) cell in my reachable set.

and one more thing, I want to lose the marking of 2's that I make when I fill, but can I do it? Or will it hurt my algorithm?

Here is my code:
(It will work if I remove all the lines with "reachable" but that's not what I want).

```
def floodfill(matrix, x, y):
    reachable = set()

    if matrix[x][y] == 0:
        matrix[x][y] = 2
        reachable.add((x, y))

        if x > 0:
            floodfill(matrix,x-1,y)
        if x < len(matrix) - 1:
            floodfill(matrix,x+1,y)
        if y > 0:
            floodfill(matrix,x,y-1)
        if y < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
            floodfill(matrix,x,y+1)
    return reachable
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, and I can't see how you would get this error with the version of the code you provided here.

Comment: I was wrong editing the mistake now...

Comment: now its correct